# Highcharts donut custom legend text before legendSymbol using labelFormatter

Tags: angular, highcharts, pie-chart

I am trying to make a responsive donut chart and with mobile resolution, I need to display the legend with some custom text on first line and symbol and name on the next line. Now, when I set showInLegend as true, the symbol is displayed first. Can someone please help me with this?

```
  responsive:{
      rules:[{
        condition:{
          maxWidth: 288
        },
        chartOptions:{  
          plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              size:'45%',
              center:[30,70],
              showInLegend: true
            }
          },
         legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal', 
            align:'left',           
            labelFormatter: function () {
             return (
               //Need to add custom text on line 1 followed by legend symbol and name on line 2
               '<div>' +this.options.name +'</div> <br>  <div>'+this.options.y +'</div>'              
             );
            }
          },
```

Comment: It is hard to tell you what could be done here without taking a look at your demo. Could you reproduce this issue in an online editor such as JSFiddle?

Comment: @DominikChudy I have disabled the legendSymbol and want to add a custom circle to the legend. I tried adding the following to the labelFormatter: <div style="border-radius: 50%;  height: 8px;  width: 300px;"></div>. But the circle is not rendered inside the legend. The custom texts are rendered inside the legend. Please help, thanks

Comment: What I am trying to acheive is: Inside labelFormatter, I need
custom text1
<symbol> custom text2.
I m using labelFormatter like below:

legend:
labelFormatter:function(){
return "<div> custom text1</div><br>" +
//"How to add the legend symbol here"?
+"<div> custom text2</div>"
}

Comment: I've already answered your question on our official Highcharts forum. For the future please do not duplicate the same questions on different support channels. Link: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=47221

Answer (score 0):

Solution is in the link : [highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=47221](https://highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=47221)